# Static vs. Instantiation

Tags: c#, static, instantiation

Assume you have a `Writer` class that writes `obj` to `fileName`. Would you rather do

```
new Writer(fileName, obj).Write();
```

or

```
Writer.Write(fileName, obj);
```

?

In case `Writer` is divided into sub methods you don't have to pass `obj` to every new method in the first case. The second approach is probably faster and doesn't instantiate a new object.

Comment: I prefer the `Static` approach

Comment: @SonerGönül what he has written is valid too :confused:

Comment: @SonerGönül You only added brackets around the new call which already returns the object, right?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I was asking if there are any more details I don't see. Maybe there is a convention I don't know.

Comment: @MarcelBonzelet He just thought the parentheses were needed, but they are not.

Comment: in .Net take a look at StreamWriter vs static methods like File.WriteAllText or File.WriteAllLines etc... you will see that static methods only do single job (although they use streamwriter internally) but you can do many stuff with StreamWriter it self. that can be much more than single command

Comment: I would make the `Writer` derive from `IWriter` and instantiate it. This subsequently makes it easy to substitute a different implementation with minimal fuss. Statics are a pain in comparison.

Comment: Why would you say "The second approach is probably faster and doesn't instantiate a new object"? Both of those assumptions are probably wrong.

Comment: Why would someone disagree without explaining himself? :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider facts as :

- Testing  is important to you ?
- Would be a problem if the Writer stays in memory (statics variables are not cleaned from memory)
- You want a software thread-safe? (they will share the same instance, so you could get exceptions/problems)

This question could help you in more depth.

[Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil)

Also to decide if you should make it static :

[Java: when to use static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods)

Answer (score 2):

This will basically come down to whether `Writer` is stateful or stateless. i.e. when you call Write, if some internal variable changes then ideally you'd want to create an instance of `Writer`

If the Write method is entirely self-contained then its perfectly valid to have it as a static method of a `Writer` class.

However, if the target was better defined, i.e. `Write(FileStream file, Foo object)` then you could choose to make an extension method rather than an entire static `Writer` class.

Comment: Good point mentioning extension methods. In my case `Writer` takes multiple objects.
I know basically when to make a method static and I agree that it should be static as it doesn't have a state. Still for more complex setups I do see the point that sub methods don't have to take all parameters over and over again.